# connected components not working for large matrix size

Tags: c++, image-processing

I have this code for finding all connected components, alongwith total number of pixels in that component, in a binary image.

```
int isSafe(unsigned char *M, int row, int col, bool visited[][COL])
{
    return (row >= 0) && (row < ROW) && (col >= 0) && (col < COL) &&     
       (M[row*ROW + col] && !visited[row][col]); 
}

void DFS(unsigned char *M, int row, int col, bool visited[][COL])
{
    indexes.push_back(count_elements);//
    indexes.at(count_elements)= ((row+1)*ROW + col+1);
    ++count_elements;
    //add index positions to array or vector
    static int rowNbr[] = {-1, -1, -1,  0, 0,  1, 1, 1};
    static int colNbr[] = {-1,  0,  1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 1};

    visited[row][col] = true;

    for (int k = 0; k < 8; ++k)
    if (isSafe(M, row + rowNbr[k], col + colNbr[k], visited) )
    {
        DFS(M, row + rowNbr[k], col + colNbr[k], visited);
    }
}

int countComponents(unsigned char *M)
{
    bool visited[ROW][COL];
    memset(visited, 0, sizeof(visited));    

    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < COL; ++j)
        if (M[i*ROW + j] && !visited[i][j]) 
        {
            //indexes.clear();
            count_elements=0;
            DFS(M, i, j, visited);
            elements[count] = count_elements;
            ++count;                
        }

    /*for (int i = 1; i < ROW; ++i)
    {
    if(elements[0]<elements[i])
        elements[0] = elements[i];      
    }*/
    //printf("%d ", elements[0]);
    return count;
}
```

M is an image of size 512x512. elements[] store total number of pixels in each connected component and indexes vector stores indices of pixels that are connected. Above code is working fine if total number of pixels in any connected components are less than 3200(approx). But, if this value is greater than 3200 this code is not working. Please help me out.

Comment: `M[row*ROW + col]` - this thing right here: if I'm getting it right, the function is supposed to check whether the row/column pixel is inside of the M matrix. If you pass the function coordinates of a point outside of the matrix, it will give you an access violation.

Comment: @tsuki This check is what `isSafe` is supposed to do.

Comment: @Gaurav Please post your [complete](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code. It appears you are using global variables whose definition is not shown above, in particular `indexes`, `elements`, `count_elements`, `count`.

Comment: @Gaurav It is possible that this is a stack overflow problem. A component size of 3200 means a recursion depth of 3200. If this is the case, then DFS recursion is not appropriate here. I would recommend union-find algorithm on a [disjoint set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure). It is not recursive; you only traverse the matrix once. And it is way more efficient.

Comment: @Gaurav Also, 8-connectedness is not needed here. 4-connectedness is enough. In case you implement union-find, you make a single pass through the matrix and at each position you only consider two neighbors, one above and one to the left. The ones below and to the right are going to be checked later anyway.

Comment: @Gaurav Alternatively, if you want to stick with DFS, you can make it non-recursive using a [queue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue). Then, DFS function contains a `while` loop that `pop`s an item from the queue at each iteration, and instead of calling DFS recursively, you `push` in the queue.

Comment: @iavr thanks a lot. First I will try it with non-recursive DFS, if still there is a problem then I will implement union-find algorithm.

Comment: @Gaurav In fact, using either a queue or a stack, the order of traversal is different than with recursion. So it's BFS rather than DFS. But the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're out of stack size. With Visual Studio's defaults, even a function who's only argument is an int can only recurse 4711 time (debug mode, my computer). You're passing more arguments, and you put a lot of data on the stack (bool visited[ROW][COL] - and perhaps more in you're unpublished code). So after a few thousand recursive calls to DFS you get stack overflow (though the actual crash may appear in new() ).
An few alternative solutions:

1. change stack size, through command line or linker options. THIS IS HIGHLY UNRECOMMENDED
2. use a vector as a stack (directly or using std::stack adapter) instead of recursion. This means, no recursion is needed for the DPS, just keep a vector of non-developed points, take the last one, find all it's non-visited neighbors, emplace_back them, etc.
3. use a better connected-components algorithm